# Setting data in jquery does not trigger in $getJson

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-ajax

Why setting data is not working in `$getJson` call. WTF variable is not set in `getJson` call. Also, another problem is why `$(this).html()` can not be set inside `getJson` call. I defined wtf variable globally but I do not get the value from the `getJson` function and I want to know why the data is not accessible. This is solved by `ajax` function and `async: seto to false`. I have my explanation but I want your explanation so thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () { $('a[id=talentNaslov]').before(function () {
             var id = $(this).html();
             var data=null;            
             $.getJSON("url", { id: id  },function (talentNaziv) {  
                    data=talentNaziv; 
// data variable is not set still null and also $(this) is not set when i use it//  
                 });        
            $(this).html(data);
            });
         });
</script>
```

Comment: How do you think 'before' will work? The problem with data is that its set asynchronously, but you are accessing it synchronously.

Comment: how du u mean synchronously what is the order of calls?

Comment: I have added some explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why setting data is not working in $getJson call.WTF variable is not
>   set in getJson call.

Setting data should be working fine with getJson, try:

```
$.getJSON("url", { id: id  },function (data) {  
                  alert(data);
                 });
```

> I defined wtf wariable globally but it does not get value from getJson
>   function and why data is not accessible. This is solved by ajax
>   function and async: seto to false.

This is because getJson is an asynchronous call, which means that the code after getJson , in your case `$(this).html(data);` onwards doesnt wait till the call back of getJson where you set `data` is executed.

So what happens is that a request to get JSON is send and without waiting for response the next lines of code are executed. This behaviour is helpful as whole program doesnt wait for comparitively long delays in fetching content over network. In your case at the time `$(this).html(data);` is called, it can only be guaranteed that request for JSON is sent, you still dont have the reply and `data` is still null.

One possible solution that you tried is setting ajax as 'synchronous' , it is not recommended and jQuery looks like going to deprecate is as its indeed a bad programming practice.

That being said, the solution is to move the logic that needs to done after getting data into `call back function` of `getJson` or the asynchronous method you are using.

> Also another problem is why $(this).html() can not be set inside
>   getJson call.

getJson has a call back function as its last argument, you are referring to this function where you have `this` as not expected.

```
$.getJSON("url", { id: id  },function (talentNaziv) {  
                 //this?? 
                 });
```

> In JavaScript this always refers to the “owner” of the function we're
>   executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of.

The owner of the function is not the jQuery Object `$('a[id=talentNaslov]')` as you think, so `this` doesnt point to it.

I still havent understood why you are using before in an awkward way, may be adding your intention along with question will get you more specific answers or more elegent ways of solving your problem.

**UPDATE**

From your comment on other answer it looks like you are looking for something like:

```
$('a.beforeme').each(function(){
    var $ele = $(this);
    var id = $ele.html();//var id = $(this).html();
    $.getJSON('/echo/json/',{id: id},function(data){
        data = {msg: "this is it"}; // you will not need it
        console.log(data.msg);
        $ele.before(data.msg);
        });
});
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PYhhS/1/

Comment: when i say setting data i mean setting wtf variable in getjson call byits response and i cant move logic inside callback function cuz it needs id as a parameter which i get earlier by parsing wanted ID of "a" tag

Comment: Did you check the update section, I have saved 'this' in $ele, so you can access the respective 'a' inside jsonCall as $ele. $ele = the corresponding 'a'.

Comment: worked like a charm ;) can u explain this var $ele what it is reference or what i mean it is accesible in geJson function and $(this) is not...tnx u very much :)

Answer (score 0):

setting the data is not working because you're trying to set the data outside the scope of the response.  Also, as a tip, you can identify the element by id using the hash sign (see below). From what I can tell, I think you're looking for something like this: (inserting the response data as the element before the link with the id of 'talentNaslov'?

```
$.getJSON("url", { id: id  },function (data) {  
    $('a#talentNaslov').before(data));
});
```

$(this).html cannot be set inside the getJson call as "this" is now a reference to the ajax (xhr) object inside this scope.

Comment: I have multiple same a takgs with same id's in page that are different by their html and href.I use this function to change their html which is Id number with text. If i use your code it will set every one of them with last value that why i want to use this to differ one value among other. And problem is that $this can not be used in getJson call even if i use global variable.